Openwrt USB Wifi not allowing both 2.4 and 5GHz at the same time
Hey all I am at a loss on how to go about getting both an 5GHz and a 2.4GHz setup in openwrt 23.05.5.
I am using a FriendlyElec NanoPi R5S with a USB 3 Panda Wireless PAU0F AXE3000 Tri-Band Wi-Fi 6E adapter.


Issue is that when I add another a new network for the 2.4GHz and save that it also then turns the AX 5GHz also to 2.4GHz for some reason?
root@carSSD:~# iwinfo radio0 info
radio0    ESSID: unknown
      Access Point: 9C:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
      Mode: Master  Channel: 36 (5.180 GHz)  HT Mode: HE80
      Center Channel 1: 42 2: unknown
      Tx-Power: 3 dBm  Link Quality: unknown/70
      Signal: unknown  Noise: unknown
      Bit Rate: unknown
      Encryption: unknown
      Type: nl80211  HW Mode(s): 802.11ac/ax/b/g/n
      Hardware: USB 0E8D:7961 [MediaTek MT7921AU]
      TX power offset: none
      Frequency offset: none
      Supports VAPs: no  PHY name: phy0

root@carSSD:~# cat /etc/config/wireless

config wifi-device 'radio0'
        option type 'mac80211'
        option path 'platform/usbhost/fd000000.usb/xhci-hcd.0.auto/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0'
        option channel '157'
        option band '5g'
        option htmode 'HE80'
        option country 'US'
        option cell_density '0'

config wifi-iface 'default_radio0'
        option device 'radio0'
        option network 'lan'
        option mode 'ap'
        option ssid 'telluridewifi'
        option encryption 'psk2'
        option key 'xxxxxxxxxx'

root@carSSD:~# uci show wireless

wireless.radio0=wifi-device
wireless.radio0.type='mac80211'
wireless.radio0.path='platform/usbhost/fd000000.usb/xhci-hcd.0.auto/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0'
wireless.radio0.channel='auto'
wireless.radio0.band='5g'
wireless.radio0.htmode='HE80'
wireless.radio0.country='US'
wireless.radio0.cell_density='0'
wireless.default_radio0=wifi-iface
wireless.default_radio0.device='radio0'
wireless.default_radio0.network='lan'
wireless.default_radio0.mode='ap'
wireless.default_radio0.ssid='telluridewifi'
wireless.default_radio0.encryption='psk2'
wireless.default_radio0.key='xxxxxxxxxx'
wireless.wifinet1=wifi-iface
wireless.wifinet1.device='radio0'
wireless.wifinet1.mode='ap'
wireless.wifinet1.ssid='OpenWrt'
wireless.wifinet1.encryption='none'
wireless.wifinet1.disabled='1'

How can I get both 2.4GHz and 5GHz configured?

Do you have the iw tool on OpenWrt? Can you run iw phy for a more detailed hardware info? As Hannu says, "client" adapters are likely to have only one radio, but the number of phys (and the 'supported combinations' list) from iw might show that more explicitly.

The info on the hardware indicates there is only one radio - which most likely cannot work on two (or more) frequency bands at the same time.
